# React, Redux and Typescript- how to get this working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I' new to React and Redux, previously I used only Angular. My first problem with learning React occurred when I tried to use Redux. I have defined my simple state, action, reducer and store in `index.tsx` file:

```
export interface AppState {
    count: number;
}

const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
export class IncrementAction implements Action {
    type = INCREMENT;
}

function opsReducer(state: AppState = {} as AppState, action: IncrementAction): AppState {
    console.log("ops reducer", action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 } as AppState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ops: opsReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App appName="Test" />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

And modified App component so it is connected and looks like that

```
interface StateProps {
    appName: string;
}

interface DispatchProps {
    increment: () => void;
}

class App extends React.Component<StateProps & DispatchProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={this.props.increment}>CLICK ME {this.props.appName}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<AppState>) {
    return {
        increment: () => dispatch(new IncrementAction())
    } as DispatchProps;
}

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps>(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

There is an error on index.tsx file:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Pick<StateProps & DispatchProps, "appName">>'.
Property 'appName' is missing in type '{}'.
```

How to fix it? How to get all this stuff working with TypeScript's hard typing? When I'll finally fix it, how to organize source code? Which things should be moved to separated files? I like the feature based code separation. How to do that with React and Redux?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key problem here is `function opsReducer`. You said type of `state` is `AppState` and *initial value* is an *empty object*. Instead `{}` write it like this:

```
function opsReducer(state: AppState = { count: 0 }, action: IncrementAction): AppState {
    console.log("ops reducer", action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: @micnyk If this solution works for you, mark answer as correct. Thank you.